# mqtt client with clean session disabled with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, mqtt

I have a Nodejs application that uses an MQTT client in subscriber mode.

This one is configured with the following parameters to preserve the messages in the queue for the client if the process crashes:

- clean session: false
- clientId: my_client_id
- qos: 1

The application is deployed with a "Deployment" object in Kubernetes.
Since the clientId must be unique, when I increase the number of replicas it will be duplicated several times.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I had thought of replacing the "Deployment" object by a "StatefulSet" object in order to be able to retrieve the StatefulSet index and concatenate it to the clientId.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Are you also using shared subscriptions to prevent all the clients getting all the messages?

Comment: No, I need the messages to be received by all subscribers and to be retained if the process fails.